I am trying to convert the where clause with OR filters to JOIN clause as I am getting error
I am getting error while running below code :
SELECT *
FROM m2_dataset_4 a --WHERE NVL(a.client,'0') NOT IN (SELECT NVL(customer,'0') FROM m1_dataset_5);

WHERE ((NVL(a.client, '0') NOT IN
          (SELECT DISTINCT NVL(client, '0')
           FROM m1_dataset_5))
       OR (NVL(a.client, '0') IN
             (SELECT DISTINCT NVL(client, '0')
              FROM m1_dataset_5
              WHERE hstatus = 'T'))
       OR (NVL(a.client, '0') IN
             (SELECT DISTINCT NVL(customer, '0')
              FROM m1_dataset_5
              WHERE client <> customer)));

Error message is :

SQL Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Null-aware
predicate sub-queries cannot be used in nested conditions:

Please let me know is it possible to convert the OR clauses to JOIN conditions. My main agenda is to choose only :

not in client
in terminated
in non primary customer


Please format your code so that we can read it.

What Kind of function is NVL?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using. (NVL is a non-standard function.)

NVL is an Oracle SQL function which returns the 1st value if it is not null, 2nd value otherwise. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NVL.html

Can more than one of the conditions be true for a given client or are they mutually exclusive?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't know if I understood your example, but an important thing is to not use IN (or NOT IN) clause when you don't have a controled number of rows on your sub table. IN clause is limited to 1000 values inside. You can use EXISTS instead.
SELECT *
FROM m2_dataset_4 a
WHERE EXISTS ( 
  SELECT 1 FROM m1_dataset_5 b 
   WHERE NVL(a.client, '0') <> NVL(b.client, '0')
      OR (NVL(a.client, '0') = NVL(b.client, '0')
        AND b.hstatus = 'T'
      )
      OR (NVL(a.client, '0') = NVL(b.customer, '0') 
        AND b.client <> b.customer
      )
 )

UPDATE
I was wrong on the condition of last code. The right code would be.
SELECT *
FROM m2_dataset_4 a
WHERE EXISTS ( 
  SELECT 1 FROM m1_dataset_5 b 
   WHERE (NVL(a.client, '0') = NVL(b.client, '0')
        AND b.hstatus = 'T'
      )
      OR (NVL(a.client, '0') = NVL(b.customer, '0') 
        AND b.client <> b.customer
      )
 ) OR NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM m1_dataset_5 b 
   WHERE NVL(a.client, '0') = NVL(b.client, '0')
 )

UPDATE 08/29/2024 14:40 UTC
Some people says that EXISTS has a low performance for conditions because it repeats the sub-query for each value. If you want to use JOIN, you can use something like this
WITH M2_DATASET_JOIN AS (
SELECT a.*
     , NVL(a.client, '0') a_client
     , b.client b_client 
     , b.hstatus b_hstatus
     , c.customer c_customer
     , c.client c_client 
FROM m2_dataset_4 a, m1_dataset_5 b, m1_dataset_5 c
WHERE NVL(a.client, '0') = NVL(b.client, '0') (+)
  AND NVL(a.client, '0') = NVL(c.customer, '0') (+)
)
SELECT * FROM M2_DATASET_JOIN 
 WHERE b_client IS NULL OR --not in client
    OR b_hstatus = 'T'     --in terminated
    OR (c_customer IS NOT NULL AND c_client <> c_customer)

